# Charging board cuts out when unplugging USB cable

Tags: batteries, usb, boost, charge, 5v

I’m using a Lithium battery charge/discharge board with 5V regulator and USB-C input to power a gaming handheld. It’s important that I be able to run the handheld and charge the battery at the same time. The board I purchased from Amazon does this very well, but when I unplug the USB cable, the voltage temporarily drops to zero and the handheld resets. The total power draw is less than 1A (not sure the exact number) at 5V. The time it takes the board to switch from external power to battery power has been measured by other at anywhere from 50ms to 300ms, so let’s say half a second to be safe. Is there anything, such as a capacitor, that I can add between the 5V output and the motherboard to maintain voltage for this period of time? If so, what sort of capacitor (or other component)? I’ve tried to figure this out on my own, but it’s beyond my skill level. Thanks!

Comment: Got any information on this charge board/regulator we can look at?

Comment: This is the board I am using. I’ve tried another with the same result (although the other drops voltage both when unplugging and plugging in the USB cable, as opposed to just unplugging with this one: MakerFocus 6pcs 2A 5V Charge Discharge Integrated Module 3.7V 4.2V for 186 50 Lithium Battery Charging Boost Mobile Power Protection PCB Board Module https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07PZT3ZW2/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_DWS9VG9AGF44R0E2V23E?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: The details on that page are so confusing and contradictory that I can't really tell if you're using it correctly or not. The problem is probably down to this KEY function they mention.

Comment: The key only acts to allow a button to turn the 5V output on and off. It’s not applicable to this problem. In fact, you could remove the board itself from the equation. The problem is simply how to maintain 5V for half a second in my circuit. Since the voltage goes down as the cap discharges, and the board actually outputs 5.2V, I’m assuming I’ll be okay with about a half volt drop over 500 milliseconds. How big a cap will that require at 1A draw?

Comment: Basic calculation of I = C dv/dt would give you about 1 Farad. The problem is you're right at the top of the operating voltage for a supercapacitor so you're looking at a very large standard electrolytic.

Comment: Any issue with using a 1F 5.5V super cap? If I can find the space for it, that is.

Comment: 5.2V is a little too close to the absolute maximum for my liking, but as long as that's never exceeded and the 5.5V limit holds for all temperatures it'll get used in it'll probably be just about ok. The supercap data sheet will help you decide.